# how to make the screen wait for user input

Tags: python, pygame

while creating my game, I came across this bug that I thought I got rid of while test playing, however when I kept trying to fix it, it made the code not work. help!

```
if stage2 == 1:
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(1)
    screen.fill(blue)
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(0.25)
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run_me = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                screen.fill(red)
                stage2 = stage2 + 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                screen.fill(white)
                stage2 = stage2 + 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                screen.fill(blue)
                stage3 = stage3 + 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                screen.fill(green)
                stage2 = stage2 + 1
```

by the way the code for color and everything else is further up the code, but lets just say that you can see it.

when ever I run this code the screen keeps flashing blue, HELP!

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: use `while True` loop to check events. And use `pygame.time` instead of `sleep` to control objects

Comment: see example [time-control-object](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/time-control-object)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you try to do but I would use `while` loop to check keys till you change `run_me` or `stage2`.

```
if stage2 == 1:

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.flip()

    time.sleep(1)

    screen.fill(blue)
    pygame.display.flip()

    time.sleep(0.25)

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.flip()

    while run_me and stage2 == 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run_me = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    screen.fill(red)
                    stage2 = stage2 + 1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    screen.fill(white)
                    stage2 = stage2 + 1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    screen.fill(blue)
                    stage3 = stage3 + 1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    screen.fill(green)
                    stage2 = stage2 + 1
```

It may not work with rest of code but you didn't show rest of code.

It will not check keys when you use `sleep()` so you may have to rethink your code and use something different. ie.

```
def wait(time)

    quit = False
    key = None

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    end_time = current_time + time*1000

    while end_time > current_time and not key and not quit:

        clock.ticks(25)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                key = event.key

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    return quit, key


if stage2 == 1:

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.flip()

    quit, key = wait(1)
    if quit:
        run_me = False
    # - or -
    #run_me = not quit

    screen.fill(blue)
    pygame.display.flip()

    quit, key = wait(0.25)
    if quit:
        run_me = False
    # - or -
    #run_me = not quit

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Of course it still may not work with rest of code as you expect.